# LESS - Nesting generates bad CSS code?

Tags: css, less

In the following article I read that one should try reduce the number of selecetors.

[Article: use less selectors](http://www.snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c/)

I'm wondering if writing LESS and I'm using a lot of nesting to group parent and child elements, will that generate bad CSS code in the end?

LESS

```
.wrap{
   width: 100%;
   height: 20%;
   background: green;
   header{
           background: blue;
           h1{
                color: red;
             }
         }
 }
```

Comment: not exactly "bad", but if your generated css starts looking like `a > b > c > d > .... > z { color: blue; }` you're going to have a hard time figuring out how to override something when you encounter that ONE `z` element that needs to be red instead.

Comment: LESS supports nesting styles, which is awesome and powerful. That said, you should always use the lowest specificity selector possible. That means you should avoid nesting unless you need it.

Comment: The linked article has nothing to do with LESS or nesting selectors in LESS. You should only nest selectors with LESS when you need to. TL;DR yes it will generate "bad" CSS code according to your spec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm using a lot of nesting to group parent and child elements, will that generate bad CSS code in the end?

In a word, yes.  In the long run this will give you highly specific, unmaintainable CSS.  Let 's have a look at what your example will produce for the `h1` style.

```
.wrap header h1{ color: red; }
```

So what you've ended up with here is a very specific CSS selector, that isn't really necessary.  You could, for instance, just have

```
h1 { color: red; }
```

or use a class on the `h1`

```
.title { color: red; }
```

### Why is specificity bad?

So imagine, 6 months later another developer comes along and they need to change the color of a `h1`, but just one of them.

First they try to add a class to the `h1`

```
.new-color { color: blue; }
```

But the colour doesn't change because the original CSS is so specific.  So they have to do this

```
.wrap header h1.new-color { color: blue }
```

or worse still they may do this

```
.new-color { color: blue!important; }
```

And then what happens when other changes need to be made?  As you can see very quickly and very easily you can end up with unmaintainable CSS, that will have everyone pulling their hair out.

### Performance

People usually negate performance when it comes to CSS, but it is always good to know what is going on when a page is rendered.  CSS is read from right to left.  Using your example

```
.wrap header h1 { color: red; }
```

This means the browser engine will search for every `h1` and check if they have a parent `header` and then if that has a parent class `wrap`.  If so it will apply the style.  A low specificity makes the rendering process a lot simpler.

### Summary

So to sum it up, nesting, whilst it may seem great keeping your code nice and readable, should only be used when absolutely necessary.  It's very easy to forget what the CSS that is actually being produced looks like.  Before you know it you'll be in nesting hell.

Answer (score 3):

Languages like LESS or SASS give you more flexibility in declaring your style rules, and that can be good or bad depending on how you use it. The more flexibility you have in a language, the more you need design patterns and good practices to avoid making things worse than they were before.

LESS doesn't *require* that you always nest. You can always use CSS of course, and if you are applying a style to all `p` it might be better to define it globally, than to call mixins to obtain the same result on several nested `p`s.

But LESS and SASS do allow you avoid duplication, to write code that is clearer and easier to maintain, and other problems caused by the code duplication required by CSS.