# LESS - Should I avoid unneeded nesting?

Tags: css, less, nested

As a result of using less I have started to use nesting more and more. It's clean and easy to follow, but I use more selectors than normal because of nesting.

For example (simplified):

```
#footer {
    background: @footer-background;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    .seal {
        width:22%;

        img {
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
    }

    .copyright {
            margin: 20px 0 0;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
#footer {padding: 20px 0; margin-bottom: 20px}
#footer .seal {width:22%}
#footer img {display:block; margin:0 auto}
.copyright {margin: 20px 0 0}
```

The first will result in additional selectors that are not really needed, but it also prevents duplication and makes it easy to find and remove all unused/unneeded/duplicated css. All of this happens because your less files have a structure.

I think that the reduction in development time is worth the extra selectors.  I think that my development time would be better spent elsewhere... but I'm not confident in that answer.

Should I avoid unneeded nesting, or is the gain worth the loss?

Comment: Your question calls for opinions and so is not really suited to Stack Overlfow

Comment: I was under the impression that LESS and SCSS optimize the selectors as much as possible. Of course, `#footer img` and `#footer .seal img` aren't the same thing...Same with `.copyright` vs `#footer .copyright`. So you can't really compare those...is it unnecessary nesting? Only until you use `.copyright` outside of `#footer`.

Comment: I just found the answer to my question in another post as well. I'm not sure how I missed it in my earlier search. [less nesting generates bad css code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175299/less-nesting-generates-bad-css-code/22175671#22175671)

Comment: You might shave a couple of nanoseconds off of browser rendering/loading by avoiding an extra selector level, at the expense of not being explicit about your rule.

Comment: @Paulie_D the answer to this is not an opinion. Too much nesting will cause the page to generate a lot of rules which will slow the render time down due to the large css file. I have experienced this first hand when building a large automobile website. It doesn't LESS is bad it jst means you have to nest efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You Can Achieve Both Organization and Minimal Specificity

It is generally recommended to use the least specific selector to do the job. If your main desire is to also do some nesting in LESS for *structural organization*, then you can achieve the best of both worlds. Take your simplified example modified:

**LESS**

```css
#FOOTER() {
    #footer {
      background: @footer-background;
      padding: 20px 0;
      margin-bottom: 20px;

      .seal {
        width:22%;
      }

      img {
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
      }
   }
  .copyright {
       margin: 20px 0 0;
  }
}

#FOOTER();
```

**CSS Output (your original shorter code)**

```css
#footer {
  background: some color you set for @footer-background;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#footer .seal {
  width: 22%;
}
#footer img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.copyright {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
```

I've used a mixin with a set of parenthesis to "group" styles related to the footer area, and call that mixin to actually output the styles. This allows me to keep the code together, and insert it "wherever" in my final output css. But the styles can then be a bit more loosely grouped under that. So I have moved the `img` outside the `.seal`, and the `.copyright` outside the `#footer`. It may be true that the `img` is found in the html inside the `.seal`, or the `.copyright` inside the `#footer`, *but if that is not relevant to selecting it*, then simply knowing it is related to the `#FOOTER()` group may be enough for your organizational needs.

This is still an improvement over merely a `/*comment*/` that sets apart a group, because it does still minimize duplication (`#footer` is not duplicated), and it does allow me to output the css in an organized way--one can envision this:

```css
#RESET();
#HEADER();
#CONTENT();
#FOOTER();
```

Inside `#HEADER();` may be some other sub-groupings:

```css
#NAV();
#BRANDING();
```

It may be opinion, but in my mind rarely should selectors require more than a single level of nesting to get the specificity needed in a well structured html page. One set of exceptions are sibling relationships, where sometimes a complex set of nesting and sibling relationships are needed to select the elements.

Of course, you have to be aware that, for example, `.copyright` is defined in `#FOOTER()` but it is outputting a selector that is not necessarily constrained to that area. If you as the designer *know* that the copyright appears no where else, okay. If not, then subsuming it under `#footer` will be important.

Comment: I would use a footer.less file instead of a #FOOTER() mixin for structure at that level. That said, I can think of situations where using a mixin for structure organization would make sense - and the more I think about it the more I believe that overuse of nesting is a bad idea.

Comment: I probably would use a footer.less file also, but my key point is that one can still utilize LESS to reduce duplication, better organize css, but not have to rely purely on nesting to bring that about (and thus keep specificity to a minimum).